# Office.Js not executing in parallel, rather its doing sequential execution

Tags: javascript

We are writing Data to a `nameRange` with office.js. Writing the same data in subsequent cells takes more time, it should have taken the same time as the data is the same.

Here is the same trace:

```
In WriteExcelTableQPromise method Macros_EnableDisable_VB Fri Apr 06 2018 18:38:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

 In WriteExcelTableQPromise method D365_BPML_InScopeData_TB Fri Apr 06 2018 18:38:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

 In WriteExcelTableQPromise method D365_BPML_InScopeData_TB2 Fri Apr 06 2018 18:38:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

 In WriteExcelTableQPromise method D365_BPML_InScopeData_TB3 Fri Apr 06 2018 18:38:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

 In WriteExcelTableQPromise method D365_BPML_InScopeData_TB4 Fri Apr 06 2018 18:38:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

 In WriteExcelTableQPromise method Macros_EnableDisable_VB Fri Apr 06 2018 18:38:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

completed In WriteExcelQPromise method Macros_EnableDisable_VB time elapsed -0.076 : Fri Apr 06 2018 18:38:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

completed In WriteExcelQPromise method D365_BPML_InScopeData_TB time elapsed -0.173 : Fri Apr 06 2018 18:38:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

completed In WriteExcelQPromise method D365_BPML_InScopeData_TB2 time elapsed -0.235 : Fri Apr 06 2018 18:38:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

completed In WriteExcelQPromise method D365_BPML_InScopeData_TB3 time elapsed -0.308 : Fri Apr 06 2018 18:38:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

completed In WriteExcelQPromise method D365_BPML_InScopeData_TB4 time elapsed -0.382 : Fri Apr 06 2018 18:38:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

completed In WriteExcelQPromise method Macros_EnableDisable_VB time elapsed -0.448 : Fri Apr 06 2018 18:38:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

How to improve parallel way of writing?

Comment: It would be helpful to see what APIs you're using, and some code demonstrating the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49726514/same-code-for-office-js-issue

Comment: kindly refer the other link Code is given -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49726514/same-code-for-office-js-issue

Comment: Any updates on this ?